# TortoiseGit Branches and tags - Confused

Tags: branch, bitbucket, tortoisegit

I am trying to understand about branches and tags with **TortoiseGit**.

I have read a few good [tutorials](http://joelabrahamsson.com/remote-branches-with-tortoisegit/) and have managed to create a branch and I can commit changes to that branch and push to **BitBucket**. And in the tutorial it shows me how to later merge to the master root.

But I don't quite understand the concept of tags. I know how to create tags. But it is getting it all to work.

What I had in my head was that I create a branch XYZ. But this branch is associated with tag 1.2.3 (a version). I thought that I could tie a set of commits (or the whole branch) to a version number. Then when it is merged later I still know what version those changes were for. Can't work it out.

I tried the "Include Tags" when pushing but that created the tag but seems to have applied it to the whole repository.

Am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Tags are just labels for commits (like branches).

Comment: You can't associate a branch with a tag; a tag refers to a specific *commit* (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging). What you're describing seems more like feature/release branches.

Comment: @MrTux So you are saying I can assign a commit a tag, like 1.2.3 XYZ

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, you are right. How do we treat a feature or release branch?

Comment: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/